# firebase appCheck is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

I'm trying to integrate firebase appCheck into my react application.

Here is the ERROR code:

[image]

And this is my code:
[image]

How to get rid of this error ?

Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 1):

For a modular version of Firebase you should import it from

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
```